# Ignoring files in specific git branches

Tags: git

Is there a way to ignore certain files in specific git branches?

Background story: As a team we use IDEA and we do want to share IDEA profile configurations but we do not want to push them to public git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Add the files to .gitignore and add the file to the project. That way, each branch can have a separate set of files to ignore.